# How to translate and answer the question?

Tags: translation, grammar

I make my homework, but I am not sure in translating of a sentence and would be glad to become an answer from native speakers. The task is to write an answer to a question. The question is: 学经济的人多不多？ I understand it so: Do many people study Economics? And this is the answer, I had written down:学经济多的人。(Many people study Economics.)

Is it possible to answer this way or the meaning is another? Or the meaning of the question is totally another? I would be grateful for your help! Thank you!

Comment: I read your answer as "People who studies a lot of economics" but then again I been in Canada for so long my chinese isn't that good any more. So to a native speaker it might not make any sense

Comment: @Huangism As a native speaker for so long time, I interpret it at first glance as "people who studies economics a lot", too :)

Comment: @Stan it seems my chinese is still ok, if someone answer with that to me, I would get it however it is not the correct way to answer. That being said, it could be because I am so used to translating english/chinese that I can understand most mistakes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is incorrect. 
The subject of your sentence is 学经济的人 （people studying economics, "study-economics-people") and your predicate is 多 (many). So putting it altogether:

学经济的人(很)多。 (positive) or 学经济的人不多。 (negative answer).

Comment: If you are not required to answer the question in a sentence, you can just say 多 or 不多. But it is much better to answer it in a sentence as this answer suggests, specially when you are learning

Comment: @Huangism Of course!